# table design for tree-like data

Tags: c#, .net, database-design, mongodb

Using other relational databases, the table looks like:

```
ID        Name         ParentID
1         root          NULL
2         a              1
3         b              1
4         aa             2
5         aaa            4
```

while using mongo db, will it be easier if we design the document like this:

```
{
   ID : 1,
   Name : "root",
   Children : [
      {
         ID : 2
         Name : "a",
         Children : [ ... ]
      },
      {
         ID : 3
         Name : "b",
         Children : [ ... ]
      }
   ]
}
```

so that the document contains only one record. Will it bring some trouble if the level goes too deep? And in this design, how can I locate one item quickly? What's the advantages of this design?

Answer (score 2):

If you will go with schema above you will have troubles with atomic updates of elements that has nesting level > 1. You can update any document that's on level 1 of nesting like this:

```
db.items.update({_id: 1, Children.ID: 2 }, {Children.$.Name: "b"},false,false);
```

But for nesting level = 2 you can't do this, because of positional operator not support it now (but it will in future i guess).

You for sure can always update entire document but it will lead to concurrency problems.

There is another schema approach to avoid this:

```
{
   _id : 1,
   Name : "root",
   ParentId: null
},
{
   _id : 2,
   Name : "nested",
   ParentId: 1
}
```

With above schema you can easy update any element in tree, but you will need build tree on the client side.
You schema has troubles with atomic updates but will work faster, because you no need build tree on client side and because of embedding usually faster + paging can be done easy. My schema is more flexible for updates, but not very good for reads. What to choose really depends on certain situation.